# swagger date field vs date-time field

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox, swagger-maven-plugin

I am using swagger to test my rest api, one of the property of my entity class is a date field for which I need the date in yyyy-mm-dd format , but swagger model schema is showing this field as date-time instead of date field, therefore it gives date with time and zone. How can I convert this date-time into date field ?

I have a java entity class TimeEntry.java one of its property is Date, it looks like this.

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = true)
@JsonFormat(pattern = DATE_FORMAT)
private Date date;
```

for this field, on the swagger UI model schema, the field date displays as "date": "2016-01-08T22:34:22.337Z" but I need this as "date":"2016-01-08" .

I have tried the following:

1.

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = true, dataType="date")  
@JsonFormat(pattern = DATE_FORMAT)   
private Date date;
```

2.Tried to follow along this code (override OverrideConvertor class) but could not find swagger-core 1.3 version mvn repo. Only available is 1.5 version https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/overriding-models

3. Apparently from 1.5 version they have removed the OverrideConvertor class
   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/ChiknyHZiP4

Please help.

Comment: From looking at the [javadocs](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html#dataType%28%29) I believe `dataType` is a java type, as in `java.lang.String` or `int`, not the "swagger type".

Comment: @ApiModelProperty is the swagger annotation , this annotation has a method dataType which takes the fully qualified path of the class of the type we need , in this case it is org.joda.time.LocalDate. In the Answer section says the same. Check the overriding property data type  section 5.3 here: http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#swagger-1-2-vs-swagger-2-0

Answer (score 16):

The problem (one of the problems actually) with `java.util.Date` is that it's really a date-time, and swagger correctly detects it as such.  I do understand that the `@JsonFormat` is a workaround for this as well--swagger does not support that annotation during it's type detection.

You have three options to properly handle date types.

1) Use Joda's `LocalDate` as the datatype.  If you declared `private LocalDate date`, it would appear correctly.

2) Use java8's `LocalDate`, same as above.

3) Tell swagger to use either of the above when detecting the type in the annotation, but keep the property as type `java.util.Date`:

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = true, dataType = "org.joda.time.LocalDate")
```

Then, when scanning, swagger will detect this as a `date` formatted string.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding to my question. I tried all the above options but the format I am getting for the date field on swagger (for all the three options) is like this.  "date": {
      "chronology": {
        "calendarType": "string",
        "id": "string"
      },
      "dayOfMonth": 0,
      "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
      "dayOfYear": 0,
      "era": {
        "value": 0
      },
      "leapYear": true,
      "month": "JANUARY",
      "monthValue": 0,
      "year": 0
    }

Comment: Can you please confirm the version of swagger-core that you're using? 1.5.6 is latest.

Comment: We are using swagger-core 1.5.3 version, also I should mention that we are using springfox-swager2 dependency . The Dependency in my pom file is : <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.fox.version}</version>
            </dependency>

Comment: Springfox uses the core swagger annotations, I suggest you open an issue in their repository to see that they update to 1.5.6, and perhaps add tests for this situation.

Answer (score 13):

My team mate has found the fix. We needed to upgrade the springfox version to 2.3.0 , previously we were using springfox 2.2.2 version. In that old version swagger's @ApiModelPreporty has attribute called "example" which was not doing anything. From the version 2.3.0 version this "example" started working. So after we upgraded the springfox version to 2.3.0 , all we had to do is as shown below.

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = true,example = "2016-01-01")
@JsonFormat(pattern = DATE_FORMAT)
private LocalDate date;
```

Below is the link from where we found this information:

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/998

Comment: Tnx ,@ApiModelProperty helped me.