# How do you change the date format in Swagger documentation?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I have the following in my model as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34750537/148844

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = true, dataType = "java.time.LocalDate")
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date mCreatedAt;
```

However Swagger is still displaying the date as a date-time-with-zone. I also tried `org.joda.time.LocalDate`. How do I change the documentation date format example?

[image: swagger api docs]

Here is the documentation on the property.

http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.3.12/apidocs/index.html?com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html

SpringFox-Swagger-UI 2.9.2

---

I noticed this error at top of Swagger UI when run.

> Errors
>   Resolver error at paths./getTrackingDataByUserID.post.responses.200.schema.properties.items.items.properties.mCreatedAt.$ref
>   Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/LocalDate does not exist in document

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.time.LocalDate`. If you interested in what is mapped to what check `springfox.documentation.schema.Types`. Here is full example:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "java.sql.Date")
private Date birthDate;
```

,which will generate the following:

```
properties: {
  birthDate: {
     type: "string",
     format: "date"
  }
}
```

Here is relevant content of `springfox.documentation.schema.Types`:

```
private static final Map<Type, String> typeNameLookup = ImmutableMap.<Type, String>builder()
  .put(Long.TYPE, "long")
  .put(Short.TYPE, "int")
  .put(Integer.TYPE, "int")
  .put(Double.TYPE, "double")
  .put(Float.TYPE, "float")
  .put(Byte.TYPE, "byte")
  .put(Boolean.TYPE, "boolean")
  .put(Character.TYPE, "string")
  .put(Date.class, "date-time")
  .put(java.sql.Date.class, "date")
  .put(String.class, "string")
  .put(Object.class, "object")
  .put(Long.class, "long")
  .put(Integer.class, "int")
  .put(Short.class, "int")
  .put(Double.class, "double")
  .put(Float.class, "float")
  .put(Boolean.class, "boolean")
  .put(Byte.class, "byte")
  .put(BigDecimal.class, "bigdecimal")
  .put(BigInteger.class, "biginteger")
  .put(Currency.class, "string")
  .put(UUID.class, "uuid")
  .put(MultipartFile.class, "__file")
  .build();
```

Comment: I don't think `java.sql.Date` type is intended to leak in DTOs exposed by a REST API.

Comment: The Types class is deprecated now, but SCALAR_TYPE_LOOKUP in springfox.documentation.schema.ScalarTypes is much the same.