# Date format time on Spring Doc swagger API

Tags: java, jackson, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to generate the documentation from my springboot application using spring doc , this is some of the attributes of the class which is causing me issues:

```
public class user {

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

}
```

With the Spring doc annotation, in the swagger i got this:

> dateOfBirth*  string($date-time)

> "dateOfBirth": "2020-04-29T14:15:32.475Z"

while i would like to have this:

> dateOfBirth*  string($date)

> "dateOfBirth": "2020-04-29"

How to do that? I think to be close to solution but i can't firugre out what i'm missing

Comment: As always, I'd recommend using LocalDate or LocalDateTime instead of the object Date whenever possible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for is here: [swagger date field vs date-time field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726086/swagger-date-field-vs-date-time-field)

Date is an object `DateTime` for swagger, as it is really a DateTime object. Use the appropriate type, like `LocalDate`, they know how to handle that.

By the way, how would you expect Swagger to properly convert a Date Pattern into the appropriate type ? It's like too much magic. Swagger relies on thing that are common practices.

The `JSONFormat` won't change how swagger interpret your data.